# Grails many to many sql

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, groovy, many-to-many

I'm trying to make a sql with grails, and I couldn't make it so far...

I have 3 domain classes:

```
class Device {
  String imei   
  List nodes
  static hasMany = [nodes:Node]
}

class Node {
  Integer signal
  static belongsTo = [network : Network]
}

class Network {
  String ssid
  static hasMany = [nodes: Node]
}
```

So, it's kind of a many to many relation with 3 tables (I need this third table, because I need to have some vars in it)

I need to find all the Networks of one device(by imei). Any ideas..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't:

```
def networks = Device.findByImei( 'whatever' ).nodes*.network?.unique( false )
```

do it?

Comment: Good idea, but I'm trying to find a list of networks. Something with findAll... However, thanks and I'll work about your answer...

Comment: @user1412935 That should return a list the `Networks` that are attached to all the `Nodes` associated with a single `Device` (by imei)..  What was it you wanted?

Comment: Yeah! You were right! The only thing is, that I need something like this, but with a kind of "distinct" thing for the networks. My problem now, is that there are many nodes pointing to the same network, and the final result shows me the same networks several times. But this was near, thanks!